# QuickSort in Perl

Tags: algorithm, perl, quicksort

I tried to implement QuickSort in Perl as I have done in Python and Ruby with the following code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub sort {
    my ($lista, $p, $r) = @_;
    if ($p < $r) {
        my $q = &partition(\@$lista, $p, $r);
        &sort(\@$lista, $p, $q - 1);
        &sort(\@$lista, $q + 1, $r);
    }
}

sub partition {
    my ($lista, $p, $r) = @_;
    my $x = $$lista[$r];
    my $i = $p - 1;
    for (my $j = $p; $j < @$lista - 1; $j++) {
        if ($$lista[$j] <= $x) {
            $i++;
            ($$lista[$i], $$lista[$j]) = ($$lista[$j], $$lista[$i]);
        }
    }
    ($$lista[$i + 1], $$lista[$r]) = ($$lista[$r], $$lista[$i + 1]);
    return $i + 1;
}

my @lista = (4, 3, 9, 2, 1, 7, 5, 8);
&sort(\@lista, 0, $#lista);
print @lista
```

In this case the execution falls in an infinite recursion and I don't know why because the code seems to be the same as in Python and Ruby (algorithm from Cormen, An Introduction to Algorithms)

Note:
If I try to execute:

```
my @lista = (3, 2, 1);
&sort(\@lista, 0, $#lista);
print @lista;
```

The execution ends and the result is correct.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I'm sure it doesn't help that your code constantly increases the size of the array while it runs.

Comment: I'm new to Perl and I still can't see were I am assigning something beyond the end of the list so it increases its size.

Comment: Tip: `$$lista[$i]` is generally considered to be less readable than the equivalent `$lista->[$i]`

Comment: Tip: `for (my $j = $p; $j < @$lista - 1; $j++)` is generally considered to be less readable than the equivalent `for my $j ($p .. $#$lista - 1)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a new version of your code, with a corrected algorithm in `partition`, expanded variable names for readability, and increased usage of Perl idioms:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub qsort (\@) {_qsort($_[0], 0, $#{$_[0]})}

sub _qsort {
    my ($array, $low, $high) = @_;
    if ($low < $high) {
        my $mid = partition($array, $low, $high);
        _qsort($array, $low,     $mid - 1);
        _qsort($array, $mid + 1, $high   );
    }
}

sub partition {
    my ($array, $low, $high) = @_;
    my $x = $$array[$high];
    my $i = $low - 1;
    for my $j ($low .. $high - 1) {
        if ($$array[$j] <= $x) {
            $i++;
            @$array[$i, $j] = @$array[$j, $i];
        }
    }
    $i++;
    @$array[$i, $high] = @$array[$high, $i];
    return $i;
}

my @array = (4, 3, 9, 2, 1, 7, 5, 8);
qsort @array;
print "@array\n"; # 1 2 3 4 5 7 8 9
```

Since you really don't want to force your caller to always use `qsort(@array, 0, $#array)` when `qsort(@array)` will do, the above code makes a `qsort` wrapper function, that takes a literal array (like the builtin `shift @array` function) and then calls the three arg `_qsort` function.

Your `exchange` implementation is rewritten as an array slice.  The leading sigil is changed from `$` to `@` and a list is placed within the `[...]` subscript.

Finally, the major problem with your code was that your end condition in partition was wrong.  Where you should have used `$r`, you used `$#$lista` causing partition to operate on far more of the list than it should.  In the code above I have used the `for/foreach` loop instead of the C-style `for(;;){...}` loop:

```
for (my $i = 0; $i <= 100; $i++) {...}

for my $i (0 .. 100) {...} # faster and easier to read
```

Comment: Curious to know why you use array slices.  If for efficiency, did you benchmark it?

Comment: @ysth => I used array slices both for increased readability and for efficiency.  The readability is obvious, and efficiency is about 15% better for the slice.  Do you not use slices for some reason?

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, $i and $j must never get out of ($p, $r) range in the `pratition` sub, which does not hold true in your code. Also when you assign something beyond the end of a list, the list will grow and `@list-1` will change, and it looks like this is happening here.

Also, a few notes on style:

1) Rename `sort` to `qsort`.

2) Call subs w/o  the leading &

3) use `$list->[$n]` instead of `$$list[$n]` -- that's easier to read.

Comment: I fixed the problem replacing @lista-1 by $r, thanks for your notes.

Comment: Frankly, I didn't know: I blindly avoid clashing with anything built-in unless on the right side of a `->`. There's too much confusion in life already, why let it into the code.

Answer (score 2):

here is a quick one with `grep`

```
sub quick_sort {
  my @a = @_;
  return @a if @a < 2;
  my $p = pop @a;
  quick_sort(grep $_ < $p, @a), $p, quick_sort(grep $_ >= $p, @a);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the entirety of @$lista by reference to the subs, so the termination condition `@$lista - 1` of the for loop in `sub partition` is probably not doing what you intended.

A stylistic note, `\@$lista` is redundant, it dereferences the list ref `$lista` and then takes the reference again, so it's the same as just saying`$lista`.

For production code it would make more sense to use perl's built in `sort` function.

Comment: Nit: `\@$lista` is the same as `\@{ $lista //= [] }`, so it's not always redundant. It is in the OP's code, though.

Answer (score 1):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub qsort(\@){
    my( $array ) = @_;
    _qsort( $array, 0, @$array - 1 );
}
sub _qsort{
    my( $array, $left, $right ) = @_;
    return $array unless $left < $right;

    my $pivot_index = _qsort_partition( $array, $left, $right );

    _qsort( $array, $left, $pivot_index - 1);
    _qsort( $array, $pivot_index + 1, $right );
}
sub _qsort_partition {
    my ($array, $left, $right) = @_;
    my $pivot_value = $array->[$right];
    my $store_index = $left;

    for my $i ( $left .. ($right-1) ){
        if( $array->[$i] <= $pivot_value ){
            @$array[ $i, $store_index ] = @$array[ $store_index, $i ];
            $store_index++;
        }
    }

    @$array[ $store_index, $right ] = @$array[ $right, $store_index ];
    return $store_index;
}
```

```
use JSON 'to_json';
use List::Util 'shuffle';

my @array = 0..9;

my $max_str_len = @array * 2 + 1;
my $format = "%-${max_str_len}s => %-${max_str_len}s\n";

for my $array_length ( @array ){
    my @array = shuffle @array[0..$array_length];

    my $before = to_json \@array;
    qsort( @array );
    my $after = to_json \@array;

    printf $format, $before, $after;
}
```

example output:

```
[0]                   => [0]                  
[1,0]                 => [0,1]                
[2,1,0]               => [0,1,2]              
[2,0,1,3]             => [0,1,2,3]            
[2,4,3,0,1]           => [0,1,2,3,4]          
[2,1,3,5,0,4]         => [0,1,2,3,4,5]        
[4,5,2,3,0,6,1]       => [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]      
[1,3,0,7,6,2,5,4]     => [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]    
[5,4,3,0,8,2,1,7,6]   => [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]  
[6,9,8,2,7,3,5,1,0,4] => [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```